# How to optimize performances when instantiating many similar layouts?

Tags: android

I have a Viewpager containing 8 Fragments. These fragments contain 30 **Custom Linearlayout** each, themselves containing 5 Horizontal LinearLayouts, themselves containing one textview and 4 ImageView.

This is a grand total of 1200 Linear Layouts, 4800 ImageView and 960 Textviews. I have created a monster (and it's barely alive). I'm looking for a way to optimize this mess.

Specifically, my **Custom LinearLayout** contains 5 identical LinearLayout, containing the same 4 icons repeated countless times.

If I'm not mistaken, every time I will instantiate a new Custom Fragment, Android will perform the calculations (Match parent, wrap content, calculate weight, fetch the background resources, fetch the icons, etc).

Is there a way to optimize this, by instantiating the Custom Layout once, and then telling android to simply duplicate it before changing some parameters?

Comment: you want to add same layout for all of your activities?? or for 1 or more activities

Comment: Since there are "5 identical LinearLayout", maybe you could replace the CustomLinearLayout with a RecyclerView as a first step?

Comment: It's one activivity reusing the same layout many times.

RecyclerView seems to be a good suggestion, I'll implement it and see how it behaves performance wise. Thank you!